# Programming Excel to conditionally format cells based on certain validity periods (tracking sheet)

Tags: excel

I am working an excel sheet that highlights certains cells base on certain validity periods. I have a cell  h3 holding validity of 4yr for a certificate. Every 4yrs, the certificate needs renewal.  Also, I have a name on row 8 holding the last certification date on h8.
How can I set excel to change the background color of h8 when the certificate date is 2months away from expiration? i.e how can i program the sheet to obey this legend

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: What cell holds the Expiration Date? Or what cell holds the Start date?

Comment: The validity date is h3. I did not include a start date... The alert should pop up every 4 years. Cell h8 holds the last time the user got the certificate. I want cell h8 to show yellow 6months to expiration, green - 2 months to expiration and red - the day of expiration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@summea thanks alot, your answer helped as foundation for enitired spreadsheet implementation.

```
            A            |       B         | C
  -----------------------|-----------------|------------ 
1 validity               |     1yrs        |     4yrs
2 last certification date|   6/12/2012     |   29/4/2011
3 last certification date|   8/05/2011     |   13/11/2013
```

i wanted a spreadsheet that would obey this legend:
[image]

using the example sheet above, the formula looked somewhat like this

```
    /* GREEN */ =IF(OR(B2="DONE", B2="done"), TRUE, AND(B$1<>0, OR((TODAY()-DATE(YEAR(B2), MONTH(B2),DAY(B2)))<((B$1*365)-60))))

    /* RED */ =IF(OR(ISBLANK(B2), B2="ASAP", B2="asap"), TRUE, AND(B$1<>0, IF((TODAY()-DATE(YEAR(B2), MONTH(B2),DAY(B2)))>=(B$1*365), TRUE, FALSE)))

    /* YELLOW */ =IF(AND(B$1<>0, (TODAY()-DATE(YEAR(B2), MONTH(B2),DAY(B2)))>=((B$1*365)-60)), TRUE, FALSE)
```

these are the formulas i used to achieve it. my final output looked somewhat like this

[image]

you can [download a copy of my demo file here](http://expertedge.files.wordpress.com/2013/04/etts-demo.xlsx). this isnt the original file, but it stood as test ground for the original. thanks guys.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one possible way to do this:

If I had columns like this:

```
  A         | B               | C
1 User Name | Certificated On | Total Days While Certified
2 John Doe  | 6/12/2012       | 294
```

I could use a formula for that third column (`Total Days While Certified`) like this:

```
=TODAY()-B2
```

**But make sure to format this "`Total Days While Certified`" column so that it displays as just a "`Number`" instead of a "`Date`" by using the *[Format Cells](http://www.addintools.com/documents/excel/where-is-format-cells/where-is-format-cells.html)* options!**

*Note: the `=TODAY()-B2` formula gives the total number of days between now and when the user became certified.  In your case, the cell number **B2** will probably be different than in this example.*

After all that, I could then use [conditional formatting](http://www.wikihow.com/Apply-Conditional-Formatting-in-Excel) for that "`Total Days While Certified`" column in order to check if the days exceed 1278 (which would approximately be three and a half years...) and make the cell yellow (or whatever color desired) to note that the user is getting close to having an expired certification.

Comment: I know this question might seem dumb... But... I'm pretty new to excel programming... Would you suggest I write the conditional check. 
Using your example, I already wrote this : c2 will hold the formula `=IF(ISBLANK(B2), "n/a", TODAY()-B2)` . That is for get the number of days while certified. I can't seem to figure out how to conditional formatting rule that will initiate the color change  At B2 .... Pls help. Thanks.

Comment: @Tamara No problem!  In order to do the conditional formatting for the color change... try looking at [this short tutorial](http://www.wikihow.com/Apply-Conditional-Formatting-in-Excel) (although the pictures will probably look a little different than your copy of Excel.)  Basically, you would probably want to highlight your `C` column (or whatever column your formula will be in...) and then add the color change rules by clicking on the "Format" (menu item) and then clicking on the "Conditional Formatting..." option.  Hope that helps!

Comment: @Tamara Just following up, but... did this answer not work for you?

Comment: thanks alot ... your formular `TODAY()-B2` and your little explanation `"After all that, I could then use conditional formatting for that "Total Days While Certified" column in order to check if the days exceed 1278 (which would approximately be three and a half years...) and make the cell yellow (or whatever color desired) to note that the user is getting close to having an expired certification"` Help alot. see my solution below

Answer (score 1):

Conditional Format For H8 based on Formula

```
=$H$8>TODAY()-1278
```

Then use Format Fill Yellow

```
    =$H$8>TODAY()-59
```

Fill Green

```
        =$H$8>=TODAY()
```

Red Fill

Or replace the TODAY() with a hard coded expiration or point it to a cell that contains the expiration.

Comment: I know this question might seem dumb... But... I'm pretty new to excel programming... Would you suggest I write the conditional check. 
Using your example, I already wrote this : c2 will hold the formula `=IF(ISBLANK(B2), "n/a", TODAY()-B2)` . That is for get the number of days while certified. I can't seem to figure out how to conditional formatting rule that will initiate the color change  At B2 .... Pls help. Thanks.

Comment: I can give you all the directions you need but what version are you using? 2003,2007, 2010 And Windows, Mac?

Comment: I'm using office 2007 for windows.